# Gitlab-runner service not started after reboot

Tags: macos, open-source

Gitlab-runner service not started after reboot. But if I login to my account, service started automatically. How start service automatically without login to my laptop?

```
uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro-Admin.local 19.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

gitlab-runner -v
Version:      12.9.0
Git revision: 4c96e5ad
Git branch:   12-9-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2020-03-20T13:02:38+0000
OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve had great luck using `brew services` to start it at boot as opposed to needing to log in.

- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html

As described, you cannot get any UI integration when it runs as a pre-log in service. For us that’s not a dealbreaker as we run those in a locked space / headless and set automatic log in but for basic use, try https://brew.sh first.

Comment: It's not official installation method. I choose auto login. See instruction in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201476

Comment: Aah, I took without login in your question to preclude that. Maybe you can answer that and make a check mark against your answer, @burtsevyg